# Vapor Queues won't compile on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vapor

I just added Queues functionality to my project. It compiles on my local machine. However, on my server (Ubuntu 18.04 running swift 5.24) I get the the following compile error:

```
/srv/www/{my project name}/.build/checkouts/queues/Sources/Queues/QueueWorker.swift:21:17: error: reference to property 'queue' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
```

I cannot edit the source code (adding the .self) as Queues is a remote package. I checked and I am downloading the latest version (1.5) of Queues.

my compile calling code is:

```
vapor build -c release
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could edit that file manually right in that `.build/checkouts` folder just to make sure that it fixes the issue

Comment: thank fixed it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [Queues 1.5.1](https://github.com/vapor/queues/releases/tag/1.5.1)